# Why doesn't TS evaluate my type parameter to its full extent and how can I work around this?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic type that is a little complex, including a union where one of the elements is only allowed if the `undefined extends` the type parameter `T`.

```
type PropValidator<T> = {
  [k in keyof T & string]:
    // simple form - just a function, implies required
    | Function
    
    // validate a required property
    | {
        required: true;
        validate: Function;
      }

    // validate a property that is allowed to be undefined
    | (undefined extends T[k] // <-- this is the key part
        ? {
            required: false;
            validate: Function;
          }
        : never);
};
```

I understand this means that `{ required: false, validate: () => {} }` isn't valid unless the property on `T` has `undefined` as an allowed value. So it makes sense that you can't use it in a generic context where you don't know if `undefined extends T[K]`.

But what about a context where `T` has been constrained? For example, `SomeType`:

```
// something you might validate
type SomeType<T = string> = {
  prop?: T
}

// a type that only validates SomeType objects
type SomeTypeValidator<T> = PropValidator<SomeType<T>>
```

We know that `undefined` will always `extend SomeType<T>['prop']` because `prop` is optional in the `SomeType` definition and therefore `SomeTypeValidator<T>` should always allow `{ required: false, validate: () => {} }`

But when I attempt to set a value to it in a generic context, it rejects this:

```
function constrainedGeneric<T extends string>(prop: SomeTypeValidator<T>['prop']) {
  prop = {
    required: false, // Type '{ required: false; validate: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'Function | { required: true; validate: Function; } | (undefined extends T | undefined ? { required: false; validate: Function; } : never)'.
                     // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'required' does not exist in type 'never'.'SomeTypeValidator<T>'
    validate: () => {}
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I get around this? How can I change my definition so that it means the same thing, but allows me to set that literal { required: false } value in the `constrainedGeneric` function?

[Playground link for convenience](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgJwPYQGoEMA2BLAJukJBAHgBUA+GAXhgG9gYYBtAaxmwDsYWowkAzGKRgAyGAGcQCTgHMAugC4GjGAHpVE7AFsImWPyJaYAWhgArAK6SY6GPwscAxiGxIOAGnY6cUcTARQAI4W2AG4yowAPjAAYg7OrhwRMMnqMABuWHgEsLYBwaFQuDAQyNAI4MnR9Cq1-kEhYQowUhZQANzJtZk4+CBQzXFOLm6ddTAAvsCpGj3Z-TYlZVAVYC0AFgTsfliYSADuRS1IMABGsA64UPycRVUwABSX17fFUAAe-Ry4fqSscl0VAB+OiA8b5RpFZr8LDiDpgupzPoDWLxEYcMbjFRTLEwZocKDpFYASk6E06oEgsAAykgtFBSFSyNQJFJZJQaDUliggc1SMAppToDBafTGdAML0CEQyBz4GVJfMZaKGUyKORpvZhokYI43JIEOhXgBxKAE6SOWUPUooZoq8VQRV9GUUJgAchtEDdcmJoMYnpZXMYEMKuGhsKg7mSSJyzQevqolFoOMmAqAA)

Comment: An interesting thing to note is there is no error in an analogous setup where prop is a boolean instead of an object: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYEtgsQQwDYB4AqAfFALxQCuyEAZighElBAB7ATIDOU+APpUjToMoAfijAATuWgAuKNRwcIAKGXVKAY3SIoGxG1YFCACgBuOaVDnxkaDAhxGAlFADeyqFHPZLZSdIBuKAB6YKZmSC1hYDgoDnINDQgGADoUzGQoJDgIDgBCVU9Q7195RQgg0PDItkYYpgkJOAllAF8gA)

Only the object fails...

Answer (score 1):

(I have had to refactor a little bit to make it clearer to me to begin with.)

I could get it almost fully working by casting the object in the last assignment (see the code), and with no need for specific type parameter constraints: now compilation succeeds/fails as expected as well as the single members of that `propValidator` look fine.

The only problem, which might be a limitation with conditional types in TS (v5.2.2), is that the type of `propValidator` in the last case does *not* get "resolved": anyway, returning it seems to work fine (see the return type of the `test` function)...

```
type SimplePropValidator = Function;
type RequiredPropValidator = {
  required: true;
  validate: Function;
};
type OptionalPropValidator = {
  required: false;
  validate: Function;
};

type ObjectValidator<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
  | SimplePropValidator
  | RequiredPropValidator
  | (undefined extends T[K] ? OptionalPropValidator : never);
};

type SomeType<P> = { prop?: P; }

type SomeTypeValidator<P> = ObjectValidator<SomeType<P>>

function test<P>(): OptionalPropValidator {
  let propValidator: SomeTypeValidator<P>["prop"];

  propValidator = () => { };
  propValidator;  // Function

  propValidator = {
    required: true,
    validate: () => { }
  };
  propValidator;  // RequiredPropValidator

  // fails compilation if `prop` is NOT optional, as expected:
  propValidator = {
    required: false,
    validate: () => { }
  } as OptionalPropValidator;
  propValidator;  // undefined extends P | undefined ? OptionalPropValidator : never
  propValidator.required; // false
  propValidator.validate; // Function

  return propValidator;
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgWzAGwgBQE4HswDUCGycAJvsFhlALxQBiArgHYDGwcWjA3AFCiRQAlCAEd6cDBGKYcBIqXKUaAb25QoE0eMkAuKMAz0IPNQDdCJMhF0MWbDjwC+PPtADyYO40LS85+RWooFTUNMQliXQAzQgBnI1UoMzlLayZWdi5uJ25ecDcAIwArCFZZCwUAHgAVAD5A4KgAbQBpKDhGKABrCBAsSKgqgF1tBIAfWEQUdGxfZIUxwREwyR8y-wwFgAomYghI9skoCAAPYAhGYhiBlsGoAH4od09vGbWyAN1GCBMIDABKRw8XL8GBYBAQKp5CpoOrKKBgGZ3XRoThQBw5FywMEQvJvSowwKuIolYB4igVUHgyGQaE1Go5SJpTx6CAxYC0zZ-XRPDIvGR+d6UBqoYDw14ChS6Sk4yBkjC0xoAIgROEVgyBahVs3KARonOodSUaOMYv5cwoqKgAHorXQmRkcprxebFEEEiElloInoDBAADTuxISqxQfVUQ1ohLZJ1mnUYS02xaacKrCUUR3W23RODIK7MMFgHNkDJtfoAAy1ZbaVwAcq4qlAcM9kH6oPgridIKwdAktXL6oHQl6orF-YGkuUQ2GI+i1A421ceRw+dr1ia+2n42pEzs9gdiEdTudLlA0FBxrv9l8Dw8l15kKmXVBPt9fr3nXGAHRD8KoxPRXMIHfWN1k-Cd5CMTM7VsB0EgkYB6AwDoNxdRxuCAA)

**ADDENDUM**:

Assuming this had to do with conditional types, I have tried this variant and indeed it *works*: the type of `propValidator` after the last assignment gets resolved (not immediately but just at the next line, see the code in the playground), and without any casts...

**P.P.S.** But now that behaviour happens *on every assignment*, not just the last one: that the type gets resolved only after first use (but I have not bothered to fix the comments in the playground).  So I must take back that this is any more of a satisfactory solution than the previous one.

As I have remarked in a comment, I think this is (very likely) a limitation/bug with how TS handles conditional types, and may be worth reporting as an issue on GitHub.

```
type ObjectValidator<T> = {  // refactored definition
  [K in keyof T]: (
    undefined extends T[K] ?
    (SimplePropValidator | RequiredPropValidator | OptionalPropValidator) :
    (SimplePropValidator | RequiredPropValidator)
  );
};
```

[Link to playground (2)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#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-c0bptRxdccrZRglBUMBA-aNRhdFm45B00S-RMAERBnBD9ZYtSjhu3QJV6hNFrZKcdxvhqDtOjFjI5Fd6zvNKWhLQRPQGCAAGilSWqVi5hqoi4jCWX7f3a7JNsuUlXt13G46aI4GQQFmA9MBgLIDJZlWAADadYNmQEADlXDqToPB1ZALygfBAW+SBWB0BJp37Q8TXUC4TyiWJL2vBU73nR8A0jNQHAAvCoUwutkEtW5jDfGdCXXTc+VeGlvl+f5ATQJUoDEvoaUhAA6VSSN-QllOPcJw03aIQOgCjN2Keg20YLAAHcuJhXiNMVABCez1PfW5lJveQjAArdbGgryTLMyzrKwvjCSgRz-wkYB6AwFlSIdESOlrfoQocpzIyAA)

Comment: Thanks Julio! Your refactor seems good and still covers the case I'm worried about - no dramas there.

The `as OptionalPropValidator` is the part I was hoping to avoid since it isn't a strict evaluation. I find it weird that `satisfies OptionalPropValidator` doesn't work - why not? As far as I can tell, that literal object does satisfy the constraint. Am I wrong? Is this a TS bug? Or does the code I wrote not do what I think it does? Am I hitting some known shortcoming in the type system? (Can you explain that shortcoming to me "like I'm 5" and is there a TS issue to reference?)

Comment: Hello Adam, I think this has to do with limitations in how TS handles *conditional types*, but indeed it is not a documented limitation, and I suppose this should be raised as an issue on GitHub. -- Anyway, as for some better news, meanwhile I have at least managed to get a better result: indeed, at the cost of slightly uglier code (which of course isn't ideal), it eventually works.  I have expanded my answer.